# Is "have to" appropriate in formal writing

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Is it appropriate to use *have to* in formal writing?  I've seen a number of posts about the meaning of that phrase but none regarding whether it is appropriate compared to alternatives.

EDIT:  Here's an example of the usage I was thinking of: 


"whether the purchaser will have to pay homeowners’ insurance and taxes"

By "formal writing," I was thinking of academic or scholarly publications.

Comment: Please define "formal writing"

Comment: Are you asking about the usage of *have to* in the sense of *must,* or as in the expressions *have to do with* (pertain to) or *have to say* (be prepared to offer into conversation)--or what?  Your two words occur in that order in many different kinds of contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"have to" is a perfect word to use in formal writings and you can use it in any of your academic/scholarly publications, unless you use something like "***hafta***".

Check out these [3,780,000 results from Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.nl/scholar?hl=en&q=%22have+to%22&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) with search phrase "have to".